# How to work with calculations in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a view with a table of products, where each product has values for cost and price. I want to calculate and display the sales margin for each product and above the table put an average margin for all products.

Where do I put the calculations? And how do you handle calculations that are cross-referenced and repeated, should I store these values somehow?

Comment: How are you modeling your products?

Comment: this is what happens when one tries to learn framework before understanding the language in which it was written.

Comment: People answering are missing the second part of the question, how do you handle a situation with rather nested calculations?

@tereško I cannot see where solid ruby knowledge would give me guidence here, please enlighten me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put the calculated values in your model as methods:

```
def margin
  price - cost
end
```

Then you can just use the margin value directly in the view.

Comment: And for all products, define `self.average_margin` containing something like `(sum(:price) - sum(:cost))/ size` which will work unless it has to take into account sales.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on whether you use these calculations in views only or not. If they are representing business logic that is used anywhere else - model is a right place. If not - helper would be a better place (or consider using Decorators/Presenters)

Comment: +1 since this is usually good advice, but I try to avoid decorators or helpers until things start getting messy. You may want to go into the console and easily be able to troubleshoot things and having this logic directly on the model will make that easy. It obviously depends on size of application, model, etc, but I prefer to keep logic in one place initially.